# App Layout changes with change in screen size

Tags: android, layout, screen

I am developing a charting application in android.
I have set all my layout parameters in dp but still I am facing issues with the alignment in different screen sizes..

Example my login button or chart goes up in a larger screen size as compared to a normal 4-inch screen.

Is this a bug in the OS version or do we need to set the parameters for each type of screen size. 
[image]

[image]

screenshot for the same login screen in two different mobile

Comment: Can you share the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of problems, align your buttons, text fields etc to the margins of the screen e.g

```
// for aligning it to the left of screen
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
// for aligning it to the right of screen
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
// for aligning it to the Bottom of screen
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Then your widgets wont change there original place respective to the bottom, right or left of the screen

dont forget to vote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layout as main layout. and add one LinearLayout layout inside it. this is the container of your login box. set the alignment to center using android:layout_centerInParent="true" .inside this container add your login box.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout >
```